# Checking if a range contains a value broken in PQexecPrepared (works in psql)

Tags: postgresql, libpq

I have this (rather ugly, generated) prepared statement to fetch some game data. I try to check if a value ($3) is contained in `spawn_level_range` (which is an `int4range`) by doing `$3<@quests.spawn_level_range`:

```sql
SELECT quests.id,
       quests.base_attack,
       quests.base_strg,
       quests.base_accy,
       quests.base_hp,
       quests.name,
       quests.task,
       quests.image_url,
       quests.spawn_chance
FROM quests
WHERE (((quests.server_id=$1)
  AND ((quests.channel_id='all') OR (quests.channel_id=$2)))
  AND ($3<@quests.spawn_level_range))
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1;
```

This exact query works perfectly when pasted into `psql` when I prepend:

```
prepare test (varchar, varchar, int) AS
```

then run it with:

```
execute test('669105577238069249', '682205516667158549', 1);
```

However, for some reason, it just does not work in libpq.

When running the statement with `PQexecPrepared`, it raises the error:

```
ERROR:  malformed range literal: "1"
DETAIL:  Missing left parenthesis or bracket.
```

(note that `1` is what I'm trying to bind `$3` to)

It seems like it's trying to interpret `$3` as a range (rather than an `integer`) – which seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your prepared statement, you explicitly declare the third parameter to be an `integer`.

In your `PQprepare` call (that you didn't show) you must have neglected to set the `paramTypes` argument to indicate the types of the parameters, so they are all `unknown` to PostgreSQL, and it infers the data type from the context.

Now there are two operators `<@` for ranges:

- `anyrange <@ anyrange`
- `anyelement <@ anyrange`

Not knowing which one you want, PostgreSQL's [data type resolution rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-oper.html) prefer the operator that has the same data type on both sides.

There are two possible solutions:

- specify the correct type in the `paramTypes` argument of `PQprepare`
- add an explicit type cast to the query: `CAST ($3 AS integer)`